In OpenMDAO, is there an indication of how long the total Jacobian takes to assemble?
The openmdao driver results object outputs timing for derivative computation time (driver_res.deriv_time). Is there any way to see how that's distributed between the sum of the compute_partials time and the assembly of the total jacobian?

Just leaving an answer here in case anyone else is looking for this as I think I figured it out:
You can use the openmdao timing reports to see the breakdown between the time to run _linearize (essentially all the compute_partials) and _solve_linear (which is from what I understand, essentially the assembly of the total jacobian.
openmdao timing myfile.py -v browser -f _linearize -f _solve_linear
